# Error de Django en Fly.io: OperationalError at / no such table: django_session

Tags: python, django

Tengo una aplicación Django alojada en fly.io. A veces cuando quiero acceder a una página de mi aplicación me aparece el error:

> OperationalError at /
>
> no such table: django_session

Dado que al acceder a la página se hace la validación desde la base de datos de que el usuario esté autenticado, aparece este error. Cabe destacar que estoy utilizando sqlite3 como base de datos.

Ya accedí a fly ssh console y ejecuté los comandos:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Sin embargo sigue apareciendo este error